# Run scrapy crawler,but can't output,log and scurce code as follows:

Tags: python, scrapy

When run scrapy crawler, I want to see the output in a cmd window. You can run this code in your ide. If you can help me, thank you in advance.

Log as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ4dK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J9xk.png

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from dangdang.items import DangdangItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class DangspdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dangspd"
    allowed_domains = ["dangdang.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://category.dangdang.com/pg1-cid4002644.html'
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = DangdangItem()
        item["title"] = response.xpath("//a[@class='pic']/@title").extract()
        item["num"] = response.xpath("//a[@name='itemlist-review']/text()").extract()
        yield item
        for i in range(2,101):
            url = "http://category.dangdang.com/pg"+str(i)+"-cid4002644.html"
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Source code：https://github.com/876309067/dangdang/tree/master/dangdang

Comment: `start_urls` should be `list` instead of `tuple` in your code, and it will not parse as it is forbidden.

Comment: I changed to list,but crawling with little information,
I think it's because their server refused to visit
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

To output to your console just use

```
print text #for python < 3
```

or

```
print(text) # for python >= 3
```

Comment: my python version is 3.6.1,so i use print(text)